# dot product of gradient with gradient of gradient of 2d field using python numpy

Tags: python, numpy, product, gradient

I have a 2D field of temperature "t" on xy plane of size 748x1500. Trying to code this function in python numpy:

f=Gt dot G|Gt|     [image: see image for symbolic representation]

where G is the gradient (upside down triangle notation)
ie.   Gt is the gradient of t

```
Gt=np.gradient(t)  # results in a list of two 748x1500 arrays
magGt=np.sqrt(np.power(Gt[0],2),np.power(Gt[1],2))  # |Gt|  the magnitude of Gt results in 748x1500 array 
GGt=np.gradient(magGt) # G|Gt| results in a list of two 748x1500 arrays
f=np.dot(Gt,GGt) # Gt dot G|Gt|   # ValueError: shapes (2,748,1500) and (2,748,1500) not aligned: 1500 (dim 2) != 748 (dim 1)
```

Comment: read docs for `dot` and `matmul` (maybe also `einsum`)

Comment: Result is Gt[0]*GGt[0]+Gt[1]*GGt[1]

Comment: The basic matrix multiplication rule does a sum of products on the last dimension of `A` and second to the last of `B`.  That's why it's complaining about 1500 != 748.  Do you understand that problem?  If you want (748,1500) then you want to do the sum-of-products on the size 2 dimension, the first of both.  Is that right?

Comment: Commonly `dot` in linear algebra is defined for 2d arrays.  But your shape is 3d.  Clearly specify which dimensions are supposed to be combined and how.  @AlexAlex's comment does do the reduction on the leading dimension.  Is that what you want?  WHy?

Comment: @Alex Alex is correct. Thank you. Final answer is to replace f=np.dot(Gt,GGt) with f=Gt[0]*GGt[0]+Gt[1]*GGt[1]